# Configuration .NET Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

So I've been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-options-and-configuration-objects), but all examples are either accessing the options in the same method in which they were declared or in a controller. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get it to work with any random class.

Here's my current code:

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Settings": {
    "GameServerVersion": 14
  },
  ....
}
```

Settings.cs

```
public class Settings
{
    public int GameServerVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<Settings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Settings"));

    JobManager.StartAsync();
}
```

JobManager.cs

````
public class JobManager
{
    private static IScheduler scheduler;

    public static async void StartAsync()
    {
        // Quartz.NET jobs
        // Setup scheduler, register jobs, etc.
        // Trying to retrieve ```Settings.GameServerVersion``` to pass it to one of the jobs
    }
}
````

Now the guide suggests I should be using the following (applied to my example):

```
private readonly Settings settings;

public JobManager(IOptions<Settings> settingsAccessor)
{
    settings = settingsAccessor.Value;
}
```

And this is where I start to get lost. I understand I could just use the following, but I don't know what or how to pass the relevant parameter to the constructor.

```
JobManager jm = new JobManager(); // cannot use an empty constructor obviously
jm.StartAsync(); // no longer a static method
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated, as I'm still very new to C#.

Comment: You should register your JobManager in dependency injection container (`services.AddSingleton` or similar) and resolve it from there instead of manually constructing.

Comment: Could you maybe go into a bit more detail? I think I understand what you mean, but am rather unsure about the implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to not perform any static initialization (like static `RunAsync` in your case) when you use dependency injection container. Instead, register `JobManager` itself (preferrably through interface) in container (assuming you pass `IOptions` though constructor as in your example):

```
services.AddSingleton<JobManager>();
```

Then, later, for example in `Configure` method in your `Startup` class, resolve it and start:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
    var jm = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<JobManager>();
    jm.StartAsync();
    // etc
}
```

If you will need to use `JobManager` in any controller - just pass it though constructor - it will be resolved automatically.

Comment: Sir, you are a true hero, thank you very much. The `GetService` part was the missing link. Is it possible to get this to work with `IOptionsSnapshot` as well?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell IOptionsSnapshot is no different. You register some stuff in dependency injection container (or in case of IOptions or IOptionsSnapshot - framework does that) and you can pass that as arguments to constructor of any other stuff registered in the same container.